# Should the "package" and "packages" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package) and [packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packages) tags seem to be used in an identical matter. Should we merge them?

Comment: Would this include package-management ?

Comment: I thought about that as well. I'm not sure either way, but [tag:package-management] seems more distinct. It deals with dpkg and/or apt. [tag:packages] and [tag:package] often deals with individual software packages. Maybe the package{s} tags aren't actually useful at all and should be completely blacklisted? I'll leave it to someone else to provide that answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't perceive any difference in how they are being used. There are currently 31 questions tagged [package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package) and 116 questions tagged [packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packages). [packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packages) has a tag wiki (however brief) while [package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package) does not.

I suggest we permanently alias  [package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package) to [packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packages).

Comment: Done! http://askubuntu.com/tags/packages/info